# Delete text outside of tags

Tags: regex, vim, tags

Using vim, I am attempting to remove all text **outside** of `<text>` blocks.  This needs to span across newlines and other (unrelated) tags.

I have attempted to use regex to substitute text for newlines, but failed for a couple of reasons, one of which was my attempts did not span multiple lines, and I need to have my matches be non-greedy.  (Is that accomplished using `{-}` somehow?)

The regex that *should* match the content I would like to delete would look like: `<//text>.*<text.*>` but if I make this match non-greedy, I may have other issues.  (I also realize I'll have one partial tag section to clean up at the beginning doing this.)

Is there another approach that I should be taking, or can someone guide me to remove all content **not** between such tags using vim?

EDIT: Including sample text

```
<contributor>
        <username>MalafayaBot</username>
        <id>628</id>
      </contributor>
      <minor />
      <comment>Robô: A modificar Categoria:Vocábulo de étimo latino (Português) para Categoria:Entrada de étimo latino (Português)</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">={{-pt-}}=
==Substantivo==
{{flex.pt|ms=excerto|mp=excertos}}
{{paroxítona|ex|cer|to}} {{m}}
# [[extrato]] de um [[texto]], [[fragmento]]
#: ''A seguir, um '''excerto''' do texto original.''

===Tradução===
{{tradini}}
* {{trad|es|extracto}}
* {{trad|fr|extrait}}
{{tradmeio}}
* {{trad|en|excerpt}}
{{tradfim}}

=={{etimologia|pt}}==
:Do latim ''[[excerptu]]'' (colhido de).

=={{pronúncia|pt}}==
===Brasil===
* [[SAMPA]]: /e.&quot;sEx.tu/
* [[AFI]]: /esˈertu/
[[zh:excerto]]</text>
      <sha1>8i1zywj37s74ah4wnai11ohorfjn8j5</sha1>
      <model>wikitext</model>
```

Comment: please provide an example

Comment: do you have only one `<text>` block in your file?

Comment: regex really isn't the best tool for this. This might be an interesting read on why its not good for parsing html. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Fdinoff I have come to realize this after attempting to solve it for a few hours.  I don't really need the full functionality of a DOM, but it looks like I need a different tool to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your struggles with regular expressions indicate that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

For text extraction from XML, you can use XSLT, which will handle all special cases far better than a regular expression. Or use special-purpose tools like [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), a kind of *grep* for XML. With it, the extraction is as easy as:

```
xidel --extract "//text" input.xml
```

Comment: I believe you are correct.  XSLT would handle this better.  Man, I hate using XSL though.  Regardless, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't NEED to you vim, you can try using this sed command, just replace "test" with the name of your file.  I would test this on a COPY of your file first since the `-i` option tells sed to modify the actual file you pass in.

```
sed -i 's/<\/text>[^<]*/<\/text>/g' test
```

EDIT: after seeing the sample, I'm going to take a different approach... instead of getting rid of all the text not within  tags.. I'm going to select all the  blocks and output it to a new file.  Hopefully your version of grep supports the -P option.  Try this:

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)<text.*?<\/text>" sample.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work.  I'm not sure that removed *anything*.  It did take a while to run though.  (The file is 9 Million lines long.)

Comment: the sample test file i was using looks like this: `<text>loijefr
ljlijef</text>afefawefa<text>efaerfe</text>eaee
<text>aeeawre</text><text>afrer</text>
`  is your end text like </text>  or <//text>?

Comment: The text tags have content in them as well.  Such as `<text annoying=true>blahblahblah</text>`.

Comment: can you provide a sample snippet ... fake the info of course  =)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is only one `<text>` block in your file. In vim this line works for your sample text:

```
%s#\_.*\(<text.\{-}>\_.*</text>\)\_.*#\1#
```

Comment: Sadly, there are thousands of them.